# file not found exception

Tags: android, file-io

Hi I am using this code for my android app so that it can capture a image and then use that image for further process, but i get a file not found exception, Can any one help on this source code can be found in the below link.

Thanks 
Deepesh

```
Exception for camera :-/sdcard/1312203454810.jpg (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 4931): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/1312203454810.jpg (Permission denied)
```

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx

Comment: have you set the permissions ?

Comment: thanks will do that and let you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permission denied. You can't access the SDCard. You need to modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add

```
   <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```